# vertex cover of size k in a degree two vertices graph

Tags: graph-theory

> Let $G=(V,E)$ be a simple graph where $\forall \ v\in V:\ degree(v)=2$.
>
> Consider the question: "Is there a vertex cover for $G$ like that of size k?"

***My approach***

Because $\sum_{v\in V}degree(v)=2|E|$ we get that $2|V|=2|E|$ thus $|V|=|E|$.

Now because the vertex cover has to have at least one representative from each edge the answer to the question is if $k\geq n/2$. Please help me and If my approach is wrong explain my mistake.

Comment: consider a lot of triangles. Is your claim true?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now if $G$ is a graph where each vertex has degree 2, then $G$ is a union of vertex-disjoint cycles.

Note that the smallest vertex cover of a cycle of length $k$ is $\frac{k}{2}$ if $k$ is even and $\frac{k+1}{2}$ when $k$ is odd. As a consequence, $G$ has a vertex cover of size $n/2$ if and only if each cycle in this $G$ has even length. If there is at least one odd cycle, then $G$ will need more than $n/2$ vertices for a vertex cover.